# Search matched list in dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, compare, predicates

```
public class Filter
{
    public List<int> A { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
var f1 = new Filter(){A = new List<int>() {1}}
var f2 = new Filter(){A = new List<int>() {1 , 4, 2}, Start = DateTime.Now, End = DateTime.AddHour(2)}

var dict = new Dictionary<Filter, string>()
dict.Add(new Filter(){A = new List<int>() {1}}, "asdf");
dict.Add(new Filter(){A = new List<int>() {4}}, "qwerty");
dict.Add(new Filter(){A = new List<int>() {3}}, "qwertyasd");
```

I need to get:

with `f1` item first

with `f2` items first and second.

How to construct linq query?

When `A` is `int`, It's simple

```
dict.Where(k =>
k.Key.A.Equals(filter.A)
&& k.Key.Start.CompareTo(filter.Start) > 0 
&& k.Key.End.CompareTo(filter.End) < 0
)
```

but when it ist `List<int>` it's more complicated for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx) and invert the control

```
dict.Where(k =>
    filter.A.Contains(k.Key.A[0]) //CONTAINS !
    && k.Key.Start.CompareTo(filter.Start) > 0 
    && k.Key.Start.CompareTo(filter.End) < 0
)
```

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>.Contains(int)' has some invalid arguments. = 
I can't use List<int> as parameter

Comment: @Saint: I edeited my post. I **suppose** that the list in dictionary *always* contains only single element.

Comment: @Tigran Better. I'll check it later, but probably shoul works

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Also 4.0. Hm, weird

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) method

```
dict.Where(k =>
            k.Key.A.Intersect(filter.A).Any()
            && k.Key.Start.CompareTo(filter.Start) > 0
            && k.Key.End.CompareTo(filter.End) < 0
        );
```

Edit: Added `Intersect` since there are two lists involved.

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>.Contains(int)' has some invalid arguments. = I can't use List<int> as parameter

Answer (score 0):

If at least one element of Filter.A must match one element of dict.Key.A, you can also do.

Cause I don't see the interest of having a List... for just one int !

```
var result = dict.Where(k =>
                           filter.A.Intersect(k.Key.A).Any());
```